# On iOS8, displaying my app in landscape mode will hide the status bar but on iOS 7 the status bar is displayed on both orientations

Tags: ios, objective-c, orientation, ios8

I want the status bar to be displayed in both orientations in iOS 8; it's being displayed properly in iOS 7.

`navigationController.isNavigationBarHidden` returns NO.

Why is iOS 8 doing this?

Comment: New feature in iOS8. Maybe only for the beta. Try with Setting.app, you'll see the same behaviour.

Comment: Have a look http://imgur.com/a/JGT4a

Comment: Right now iOS 8 is beta version. Can be fixed in official release i.e in Sep, same thing faced when they have released iOS 7.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

**Try this**

Add below code in `didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation`

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:NO withAnimation:UIStatusBarAnimationNone];
```

**EDIT**
**NO NEED TO WRITE CODE IN ALL VIEW CONTROLLER**
Set `View controller-based status bar appearance` to `NO` in `plist` and add below code in 
root view controller's `viewDidLoad`

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES withAnimation:UIStatusBarAnimationNone];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:NO withAnimation:UIStatusBarAnimationNone];
```

**Demo project**
https://www.dropbox.com/s/uumneidk4wom5md/demoStatusBar.zip?dl=0

Comment: we will have to write this code in every view controller, right?

Comment: thanks for the replay and demo project. In my case my root view controller keep on changing all the time. So will have to write in every root view controller

Comment: just try to code in once first root view controller, may help

Comment: This appears to be the best solution, with one minor suggested change i.e. use `application:FinishLaunchingWithOptions:` to force the status bar hidden state.

Comment: Will it work with trait collection did change also? Really? With iOS 9?;) please confirm this...

Comment: It is deprecated since iOS 9.

Answer (score 49):

To display status bar in landscape mode in ios 8, try following method

```
- (BOOL)prefersStatusBarHidden {
    return NO;
}
```

Swift version

```
override func prefersStatusBarHidden() -> Bool {
    return false
}
```

Swift 3, Xcode 8, iOS 10, /* ViewController.swift */

```
override var prefersStatusBarHidden: Bool {
        return false
    }
```

Comment: For Swift :  override func prefersStatusBarHidden() -> Bool {
        return false;
    }

Comment: It works only if you has set _View controller-based status bar appearance_ in your plist file to YES.

Answer (score 9):

Jageen's solution is probably the best, with just one minor change i.e. instead of using `viewDidLoad`, it's better to use `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:`.

It's basically a two step process:

1). Set "View controller-based status bar appearance" to NO, in your project's Info.plist file.

2). Force the status bar hidden status to NO, in `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:`, using the following code:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES withAnimation:UIStatusBarAnimationNone];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:NO withAnimation:UIStatusBarAnimationNone];
```

And, voila!

**Note:** It's important to use both the `setStatusBarHidden:withAnimation` statements above, to force the status bar hidden state.

Comment: A note: You don't need to call `[UIApplication sharedApplication]` in `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:`, because there is a method argument `application`. Thus, just call `[application setStatusBarHidden:...]`.

Answer (score 6):

It's not an issue but a feature of an iOS 8. The status bar will be hidden in landscape mode in iOS 8, even Apple's applications also having same behaviour.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same issue! Fixed by addicting this to viewDidLoad

```
  [self setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate];
```

And this to implementation itself

```
-(BOOL)prefersStatusBarHidden{
    return NO;
}
```

Comment: we will have to write this code in every view controller, right?

Answer (score 4):

They are keeping us gainfully employed by giving us more work.

or...

They've made other changes which cause bits to take up more space than they used to. With iOS 7 and the advent of things like the "Top Layout Bar Guide", the easy availability of the status bar in the swipe down screen, reclaiming the status bar space to be usable and other little hints many people predicted the status bar might be getting phased out as a standard part of the UI.

There is also quite a bit of buzz about new device sizes due to the changes they've made in iOS 8 trying to make it easier to code for a bunch of different sizes.

It's pure speculation, but I don't think they landscape status bar will return in iOS 8.

Answer (score 3):

**Swift 3**

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        UIApplication.shared.setStatusBarHidden(true, with: .none)
        UIApplication.shared.setStatusBarHidden(false, with: .none)
///
    }
```

and add inside `Info.plist` this:

`UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance`  boolean value `NO`

Answer (score 1):

**Swift 3**  *(As of June 2, 2017)*

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear()
    self.setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate()
}

override var prefersStatusBarHidden : Bool {
    return false
}
```

Answer (score 0):

We fixed it by following the above steps and making sure that landscape left and right are both enabled.

Under Project/Target/Deployment Info

[image]

Answer (score -2):

We solved this by forcing an orientation change unseen by the user.  In the first view controller that loads, add:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    NSNumber *orientationLeft = [NSNumber numberWithInt:UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft];
    NSNumber *orientationRight = [NSNumber numberWithInt:UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight];
    [[UIDevice currentDevice] setValue:orientationLeft forKey:@"orientation"];
    [[UIDevice currentDevice] setValue:orientationRight forKey:@"orientation"];
}
```