# Issue of status bar which is getting hidden in landscape mode in ios 8 and works fine in ios 7 tried after release of ios 8 in xCode 6

Tags: ios8, statusbar, xcode6

I've got an issue with the status bar which is hidden when the simulator is rotated in landscape mode in iOS 8, while it works fine in iOS 7 simulators.

What should I do to resolve this issue ?

Comment: The accepted answer of this question fixed this issue:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24329503/on-ios8-displaying-my-app-in-landscape-mode-will-hide-the-status-bar-but-on-ios

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is the new default in iOS 8. But you can restore the old behavior by overriding the following in your `UIViewController`:

```
- (BOOL)prefersStatusBarHidden {
    return NO;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

The below simple solution is working great for me in `iOS 8` without any issues.

```
- (void)viewWillTransitionToSize:(CGSize)size withTransitionCoordinator:(id<UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator>)coordinator {

     [coordinator animateAlongsideTransition:^(id<UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinatorContext> context)
      {
         [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:NO];

      } completion:^(id<UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinatorContext> context)
      {

      }];

     [super viewWillTransitionToSize:size withTransitionCoordinator:coordinator]; 
}
```

Comment: Works in iOS 10 as well.

Answer (score 2):

It's not an issue but a feature of IOS 8. The status bar is hidden in landscape mode in IOS 8

Comment: you are correct, even Apple app's also having same behaviour.

Comment: Not all Apple apps / components have the status bar hidden in landscape. AVVideoPlayer is one example.