# Xcode 6.x/iOS 8 Hides Status Bar in Landscape Orientation

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode6

Application build with Xcode 6.x automatically hides the status bar in Landscape orientation (iPhone). The same application when compiled with Xcode 5.x doesn't do that.

How can I prevent the application from hiding the status bar in Landscape orientation? Basically, how can I disable this "super awesome" feature that Apple/Xcode has shoved down my throat?

p.s. I've tried updating the view controllers with the following code, but it doesn't help.

```
- (BOOL)prefersStatusBarHidden {
    return NO;
}
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

**Best possible solution**

It's basically a two step process:

1). Set "View controller-based status bar appearance" to `NO`, in your project's Info.plist file.

2). Force the status bar hidden status to `NO`, in `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:`, using the following code:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES withAnimation:UIStatusBarAnimationNone];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:NO withAnimation:UIStatusBarAnimationNone];
```

And, voila!

Note: It's important to use both the `setStatusBarHidden:withAnimation:` statements above, to force the status bar hidden state.

---

Reference: [On iOS8, displaying my app in landscape mode will hide the status bar but on iOS 7 the status bar is displayed on both orientations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24329503/on-ios8-displaying-my-app-in-landscape-mode-will-hide-the-status-bar-but-on-ios/25671226)

Answer (score 1):

I'm using

```
#define IS_IOS8 SYSTEM_VERSION_GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL_TO(@"8.0")

-(void)willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration{
    [super willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:toInterfaceOrientation duration:duration];

    if (IS_IOS8){
            [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:NO];
    }
}
```

Comment: `-willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation` is deprecated

Answer (score 0):

Set "View controller-based status bar appearance" to **YES** in **Info.plist**

Then place the following code in the desired view controller:

```
- (BOOL)prefersStatusBarHidden {
    return NO;
}
```