# How to hide status bar in iOS 8.2 in iPhone 6 device?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, hide, statusbar

By using "UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance" made to "NO", we are able to hide the status bar in <= iOS 8.1 (all devices).  But Its not working in only iOS 8.2 version in only iPhone 6 & 6+ devices. Can anyone help me out ??

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26146012/hide-status-bar-in-ios-8-app also check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26487170/xcode-6-x-ios-8-hides-status-bar-in-landscape-orientation

Comment: You can create UIView with state bar size and add it to your view.

Comment: you can try

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26146012/hide-status-bar-in-ios-8-app

Answer (score 1):

[image]In your apps plist file add a row call it "View controller-based status bar appearance" and set it to NO.

OR Try this one also.`

```
-(BOOL)prefersStatusBarHidden{
    return YES;
}
```

`

Comment: In my .plist file this property is not there.

Comment: @AshokLondhe then use that method.

Comment: i have two view controller and when i go to next on next view controller status bar appears and when i come back to first screen the NavigationBar item(RightBarButtionItem) get hidden or removed.

Comment: go to project target and enable "hide status bar". Then it will hide the entire  project.

Comment: there is no such property.

Comment: 'Status bar is initially hidden' is the property

Answer (score 0):

You really should implement prefersStatusBarHidden on your view controller(s):

```
override func prefersStatusBarHidden() -> Bool {
    return true
}
```

if your using swift you can use this code otherwise above code.