# Status bar behave weird in landscape mode on iOS 8.1 and work fine with iOS 7.1

Tags: ios, iphone, statusbar, uiinterfaceorientation, ios8.1

I am having very uncommon problem. Im my application the status bar does not show in landscape mode. This issue happen only for iOS 8. It work fine in iOS 7. Please see the attached screen shots for both iOS 7 and iOS 8.

[image: iOS7.1 portrait]
[image: iOS7.1 landscape]
[image: iOS8.1 portrait]
[image: iOS8.1_landscape]

Comment: possible duplicate of [On iOS8, displaying my app in landscape mode will hide the status bar but on iOS 7 the status bar is displayed on both orientations](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24329503/on-ios8-displaying-my-app-in-landscape-mode-will-hide-the-status-bar-but-on-ios)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may help you

In Plist set View controller-based status bar appearance: NO

and add the code in your view Controller

```
-(void)didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)fromInterfaceOrientation
{
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:NO withAnimation:UIStatusBarAnimationNone];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

check if you got any code similar like:
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES withAnimation:UIStatusBarAnimationNone];

and besides, you need to check if in your storyboard, or xib related, if any status bar is set to none