# Button not appearing in landscape mode in iOS 8

Tags: ios, iphone, autolayout

I have one button, i set it's constraints to "Horizontal centre" and "Vertical centre". It is appearing in centre as expected in portrait mode. But the moment when i rotate the device to landscape mode, the button disappears and status bar also not visible.

Comment: first in iOS8 status bar is not visible in landscape mode, so that's not a problem, second remove all constraint and then try again, may be it other constrain which are causing the problem.

Comment: give detail description under which environment you are developing application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Here is a screen which show constraint needed to show button in centre in both landscape and portrait mdoe** 
[image]

**This is a simplest thing i ever post in stackoverflow

Please check your code again and see is there any other constrains you had apply.**

---

**Note :** In iOS8 status bar is hide in landscape mode and if you want to display it in landscape mode please follow my answer over here [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24329503/on-ios8-displaying-my-app-in-landscape-mode-will-hide-the-status-bar-but-on-ios/25671226#25671226).

Answer (score 0):

have you fixed the **height** and **width** of the `UIButton`? if not add  **height** and **width** `constraints` to the `UIButton`

Answer (score 0):

Check the size class for which you set the constraints. If you are not aware of size classes watch the wwdc 2014 video titled "Building Adaptive Apps with UIKit".