# Hide status bar in portrait mode in iOS8

Tags: ios8, statusbar

I've followed the instructions here [On iOS8, displaying my app in landscape mode will hide the status bar but on iOS 7 the status bar is displayed on both orientations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24329503/on-ios8-displaying-my-app-in-landscape-mode-will-hide-the-status-bar-but-on-ios)

i.e. set status bar hidden in plist and adding:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES withAnimation:UIStatusBarAnimationNone];
```

but am still unable to hide the Status bar. Any further suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Select the view controller for which you have hide the status bar and set the status bar parameter to NONE as given in the image below:

[image]